# Word 2010 Interop: Show the "Save As" dialog

Tags: c#, .net, interop, word-2010

I need a way to always show the save as dialog when the user performs a certain action on a Word document.  Currently, the dialog only shows when an unsaved document is saving.  These documents I am working on have already been saved in one location with a particular name, but users will need to be able to change the name and the location.

Comment: Can you add the code snippet you are using to save? I think there may be a parameter overload, or a property that can be set on the instance to force this.

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out.  Very simple, in case someone else runs into the same issue:

```
var wordDialog = 
Globals.ThisDocument.ThisApplication.Dialogs[Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFileSaveAs];
wordDialog.Show();
```